# Puppeteer: does page.goto waitUntil option includes open web sockets?

Tags: puppeteer

I'm using node js v10 and puppeteer v1.10 in a docker container.

I need to take a screenshot of a page which has 2 web sockets open. They return some data as soon as the page loads, but after that they remain idle.
When I abort the requests to the web socket endpoint, the page loads correctly and I can take a screenshot. If I don't, puppeteer throws a timeout error (`Navigation Timeout Exceeded: 120000ms`).
Does the option `page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});` includes web sockets (which, in that case, the connection remains open but idle forever) or just normal requests to i.e. css / image / api resources?

At the moment, I'm able to take a screenshot if I set:

```
page.on('request', (request) => {
    if(request.url().includes('socket.io')) {
      console.log("Blocking websocket: ", request.url());
      request.abort();
      return;
    }
  request.continue();
});
page.goto(url, {waitUntil: 'networkidle0'});
```

Answer (score 0):

Before opening websocket connection, socket.io will try to poll using ajax and then on another request it will switch the protocols saying "101 Switching Protocols".

`waitUntil` won't wait for websocket connections because they are usually pending forever. You are correct to block it if the websocket server is down.

Here is how it looks like on network tab.

[image]